# Connect Apache Kafka to a database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create a streaming/big-data application with PostgreSQL, Apache Kafka (to send data) and Apache Spark Streaming (to process the data).

Following this [document](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html), I first try to connect Kafka to a Sqlite database. But when I run the connector with the command

```
$ ./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-sqlite.properties
```

I got the errors below, before the process shutdown. I pass the correct path to my database, I verified.

How can I connect and work the connection between my database & Kafka ?

```
2017-09-11 12:00:17,305] INFO jetty-9.2.15.v20160210 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:327)
Sep 11, 2017 12:00:17 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.

[2017-09-11 12:00:17,618] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1a2d50d5{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:744)
[2017-09-11 12:00:17,623] WARN FAILED ServerConnector@3e37a981{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle:212)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.start(RestServer.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect.start(Connect.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:82)
[2017-09-11 12:00:17,624] WARN FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@46eb180e: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle:212)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.start(RestServer.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect.start(Connect.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:82)
[2017-09-11 12:00:17,624] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:100)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to start REST server
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.start(RestServer.java:147)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect.start(Connect.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:82)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.start(RestServer.java:145)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WARN FAILED ServerConnector@3e37a981{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle:212)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

This means that something else is already using port 8083.

Are you using [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/)? This is a great way to get started with Apache Kafka, and gives you an easy way to bring up the stack (`confluent start`) as well as configure Kafka Connect. This blog series shows it in action:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

BTW you might want to check out [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) too, as a way of doing stream processing within Kafka itself.

Comment: I am using the Confluent Platform, and yes, I am following the documentation. I just want to try to make things work with a sqlite database, before doing it with a postgres database.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. `confluent start` will also start Connect. So you can either use `confluent load` to add the configuration file that you have, or if you want to use the quickstart as-is, run `confluent stop connect` first, which will release port 8083.

Comment: But Connect is necessary for database connection. Or did I not really understand ?

Comment: Yes you use Kafka Connect. But you instantiate it once (either as part of `confluent start`, **or** by launching `connect-standalone`. At the moment the error you're getting is basically _because it's already running_ when you're executing `connect-standalone` and thus the error on port conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the `listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081` property in the `schema-registry.properties` file and the issue was resolved.

Your port number is probably `8083`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in `Kafka 3.0` the property `rest.port=<port>` is deprecated and now you must use `listeners=<http:port>`